# pushing data from UITableView to another UIViewController on the same screen

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller

have a question. I have an ipad app that contains a View Controller with a `UITableView` and a detail view (which is basically another view controller to display details) on the same screen. I need to pass the row data from `UITableView` when the `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is executed to this detail view. I am not sure how to go about doing this? Any help/pointers/sample code on how to go about doing this?

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a delegate in the UITableView view controller, and implement it in the detail view controller.  When didSelectRowAtIndexPath is invoked, call the delegate method, passing the row data to the detail view controller.

The delegate definition will look something like:

```
@class MyTopLevelViewController;

@protocol MyTopLevelViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)showDetail:(DetailObject *)detail;

@interface MyTopLevelViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyTopLevelViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

and adding the delegate to the detail view controller header:

```
@interface MyDetailViewController : UIViewController <MyTopLevelViewControllerDelegate>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are willing to pass the data on another view controller in didSelectRowAtIndexPath on same screen, you can use array as you get "objectAtIndex:indexPath.row". Following code might help you:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DetailFoodViewController *detailFoodViewController=[[DetailFoodViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"DetailFoodViewController" bundle:nil];

    JSCategory *jSCategory=[self.categoryResult.JSCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    detailFoodViewController.jsCategory=jSCategory;

    detailFoodViewController.oldStoreLocationId=self.oldStoreId;

    [self.view addSubview:detailFoodViewController.view];
    [detailFoodViewController release];

}
```

Comment: I would disagree with your way to presenting the view of the new view controller. If you are not implementing UIViewControllerContainment, adding the view of a view controller as a subview in another way controller is a bad idea and will make things messy. Presenting the new viewController modally, or pushing it, is a better way to present a viewController from another viewController. If it's necessary to be on the same view: use contaiment.